# Xindy not working on non-root drive

Tags: xindy, perl

I've just been using texlive for a few years on my Win10 computer and so far I wasn't facing any difficulties. However since I don't have enough space on the C: drive, I had to install it on another drive (F:). The problem is when I try to use the package Xindy, it gives me "No such file or directory". Entering "xindy --version" in cmd yields me this:

```
C:\>xindy --version /c/f:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/xindy/../../xindy/modules: No such file or directory at f:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 408.
F:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2: perl.exe f:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl --version
```

So I checked line 408 on xindy.pl, and it is this:

```
    $modules_dir = Cwd::realpath("$cmd_dir/../../xindy/modules");
```

I tried change the above line manually to this:

```
    $modules_dir = Cwd::realpath("F:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/xindy/modules");
```

However now, i get this error:

```
f:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl: not a symlink as required for TeX Live at f:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 424.
```

Since xindy just works fine in my notebook which has texlive installed on the root drive, I assume that causes the problem. Is there any workaround or hack for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: What happens if you call xindy from F:?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get the same error:

/f/f:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/xindy/../../xindy/modules: No such file or directory at f:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 400.